# Always getting Undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am using Multer to upload multiple files to the server. I tried different code strategies but always getting Undefined value in the I have tried Multer using Express.js and Handlebars but getting Undefined value every time

Handlebrs: This is my Handlebars file

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/newRequest" 
            enctype="multipart/form- 
      data" >
<input type='text' name="fname">
<input type="file"  name="first">
<input type="file" name="doc2Request">
<input type="file" name="doc3Request">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="" value="submit">
</form>
```

Multer Config:This is the Multer configuration

```
var multer = require('multer');
const multerConfig = {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './public/uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());

    }
  })
}

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Route:

```
    route.post('/admin/newRequest', upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.files);
      console.log(req.body);
    });
```

I want to get the files and input of all of these four inputs.

Comment: i wants to get the files and input of all of these four inputs.

Comment: Added comment to question

Comment: Is there actually a line break in the middle of `multipart/form-data`? Because there can’t be.

Comment: No there is no Line break in the actual code